# Enum: Did I just do something unwanted?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum class which has several constants, and I want to add some static value `FOCUSED` which indicates which of the enum values has focus...

I found a way:

```
package messagesystem;

/**
 *
 * @author Frank
 */
public enum MessageType {
    ALL,
    GENERAL,
    SEND,
    RECEIVE,
    LOG,
    EXCEPTION,
    DEBUG,
    PM;

    public final static MessageType FOCUSED = GENERAL;

    private final String value;

    MessageType() {
        String firstLetter = name().substring(0, 1);
        String otherLetters = name().substring(1, name().length());
        this.value = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + otherLetters.toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

However, now I wonder: Did I just mess with the enum class? Because I don't want `FOCUSED` to be selectable when specifying the message type, however a class handling an enum of `MessageType` should be able to determine the `FOCUSED` value... Such that I do not need to hardcore it in every class.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

EDIT: It is behaving correctly though.
This code gives the expected output:

```
    this.focused = MessageType.FOCUSED.toString();
    System.out.println(focused);
```

The output is "General".

Comment: "a class handling an enum of MessageType should be able to determine the FOCUSED value" - it's really not clear what you mean by this. With the code you've given, the `FOCUSED` value is *always* `GENERAL`

Comment: That is true, the idea is that if I want to change `FOCUSED` at a later point in developemtn, that I then only need to change it in one place. In contrary to every variable imitating the `FOCUSED` value by hardcoding it to `GENERAL`.

Comment: So you really want it to be effectively a constant - an alias, almost? *If* that is the case, that's fine - but that doesn't really go alongside "some static value FOCUSED which indicates which of the enum values has focus" - because that sounds like a piece of *state* which can vary. It's partly unclear because it's not obvious what it means for a message type to have focus in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FOCUSED is just an alias to GENERAL. It won't appear in the `values()` of the enum, and if some client code uses FOCUSED, it will in fact use GENERAL, as both variables refer to the same enum value. So no, I don't think you messed up.

To reduce the confusion, maybe you should make `focused()` a static method, which returns GENERAL. This would also avoid the need to recompile client code in case you decide that the focused type is another one.

Comment: I want to emphasize the importance of usingt a static method (instead of a static final variable) for this.  In Java, static final constants are resolved at *compile* time.  If you changed the value of the constant, any class already compiled would continue to retain the old value.  JB's advice here seems subtle, but it is not - it's very important!

Comment: @KevinDay Wow ok, I had to read it a few times to fully grasp the message. But that is indeed a big deal and may cause serious issues. Thank you for pointing this out, moreover by making it a static method I also ensure myself that I cannot pick `FOCUSED` as an enum of `MessageType`, which I think Netbeans still allows me to do.